# Transactions in Entity Framwork6

Tags: ado.net, entity-framework-6

I have the code with following structure

```
public class Migration
        {
     public bool addNewData()
            {
                using(TransactionScope tScope=new TransactionScope())
                    { 
                   Entities dataContext = new Entities(); //context object

                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                        {
                        Issue issuelst = new Issue(); //Table Name
                        //Add data 
                        dataContext.Issues.Add(issuelst);
                        dataContext.SaveChanges();
                        }

                     foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                        {
                        IssueList lst = new IssueList(); //Table Name
                        //Add data 
                        dataContext.IssueLists.Add(lst);
                        dataContext.SaveChanges();
                        }
    ReadFileData readFileData = new ReadFileData(); //Class object
    readFileData.ReadData();
    tScope.Complete();
                    }
            }
    }

    Class ReadFileData
       {
    public bool ReadData()
         {
            //Data
ReadData2();
         }

 public bool ReadData2()
         {
            //Data
         }
       }
```

So the issue I am facing is with transactions. In addNewData transaction is working fine.
But its not working in ReadData and ReadData2 function which is inside ReadFileData class 
All the functions are dependent. I mean to day that if there is some issue or exception in ReadData2 function, data inside function ReadData and addNewData should not get saved.
How to do this. Need Help

Comment: can anyone please help!!

Comment: Are you saving data to the same database in the ReadData and ReadData2 methods?  If so can you use the same dataContext in the methods?  If you can, you only need to call SaveChanges once and EntityFramework will manage the transaction for you.